# How to properly use discriminate union in typescript so when one property is true two additional property is required

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I  want to make a react component in typescript with values of two properties dependent on one other property.

here is the code I wrote:

```
 interface IHeaderDataBasic {
    text:string;
    key:string;
    columnSpan?:number;
}

 interface IHeaderSortTrue extends IHeaderDataBasic {
    sortIcon:true;
}

 interface IHeaderSortFalse extends IHeaderDataBasic {
    sortIcon?:false
}

 interface ITableHeaderSortFalse {
    headerArray : IHeaderSortFalse[];
    sortState?:undefined;
    sortFunction?:undefined;
}
 interface ITableHeaderSortTrue  {
    headerArray : IHeaderSortTrue[] | (IHeaderSortTrue|IHeaderSortFalse)[];
    sortState:SortColumnValue;
    sortFunction:(key:string) => void;
}

props:ITableHeaderSortFalse | ITableHeaderSortTrue
```

I should be able to call the component is such a way

```
<Component
headerArray = {IHeaderSortTrue[]}
sortState = {SortColumnValue}
sortFunction = {(key:string) => void}
/>

<Component
headerArray = {IHeaderSortFalse[]}
/>

<Component
headerArray = {IHeaderSortFalse[]}
sortState = {undefined}
sortFunction = {undefined}
/>

<Component
headerArray = {(IHeaderSortTrue|IHeaderSortFalse)[]}
sortState = {SortColumnValue}
sortFunction = {(key:string) => void}
/>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions):

```
type NetworkLoadingState = {
  state: "loading";
};
type NetworkFailedState = {
  state: "failed";
  code: number;
};
type NetworkSuccessState = {
  state: "success";
  response: {
    title: string;
    duration: number;
    summary: string;
  };
};
// Create a type which represents only one of the above types
// but you aren't sure which it is yet.
type NetworkState =
  | NetworkLoadingState
  | NetworkFailedState
  | NetworkSuccessState;
```

Then, create a new variable of type `NetworkState`. The other properties will become available depending on the value of `state`.